# How to set deployment group in release Pipeline by api

Tags: azure-devops

I try to create a release pipeline via Azure devops api. As phaseType I want to use machineGroupBasedDeployment (Deployment Group). But how can I set the Deployment group in the deployment phase? If I use the json  below as request the deployment group is always empty. Has anybody an idea or an sample how I can set the deployment group?

```
"deployPhases": [
        {
          "deploymentInput": {
            "healthPercent": 0,
            "deploymentHealthOption": "Custom",
            "tags": [],
            "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
            "artifactsDownloadInput": {
              "downloadInputs": [
                {
                  "alias": "_xxx ch",
                  "artifactType": "Build",
                  "artifactDownloadMode": "All",
                  "artifactItems": []
                }
              ]
            },
            "queueId": 129,
            "demands": [],
            "enableAccessToken": false,
            "timeoutInMinutes": 10,
            "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "overrideInputs": {}
          },
          "rank": 1,
          "phaseType": 4,
          "name": "IIS Deployment111",
          "refName": null,
          "workflowTasks": [
            {
              "environment": {},
              "taskId": "1b2aec60-dc49-11e6-9b76-63056e018cac",
              "version": "0.*",
              "name": "IIS Web App Manage",
              "refName": "",
              "enabled": true,
              "alwaysRun": false,
              "continueOnError": false,
              "timeoutInMinutes": 10,
              "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
              "definitionType": null,
              "overrideInputs": {},
              "condition": "succeeded()",
              "inputs": {
                ....
```

Comment: Rather than messing around with JSON and classic pipelines, why not just use YAML pipelines, where everything is well-documented and templates are a first-class citizen?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I set the Deployment group in the deployment phase?

In the RequestBody, you can define the **Deployment Group Id** in the **queueId** field and the **phaseType** is **machineGroupBasedDeployment**.

For example:

```
"deployPhases": [
                {
                    "deploymentInput": {
                        "healthPercent": 0,
                        "deploymentHealthOption": "Custom",
                        "tags": [],
                        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                        "artifactsDownloadInput": {
                            "downloadInputs": []
                        },
                        "queueId": {DeploymentGroupID},
                        "demands": [],
                        "enableAccessToken": false,
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "overrideInputs": {}
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "phaseType": "machineGroupBasedDeployment",
                    "name": "Deployment1 group job",
                    "refName": null,
                    "workflowTasks": [
                        {
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                            "version": "2.*",
                            "name": "PowerShell Script",
                            "refName": "",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "succeeded()",
                            "inputs": {
                                "targetType": "inline",
                                "filePath": "",
                                "arguments": "",
                                "script": "# Write your PowerShell commands here.\n\nWrite-Host \"Hello World\"\n",
                                "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                                "warningPreference": "default",
                                "informationPreference": "default",
                                "verbosePreference": "default",
                                "debugPreference": "default",
                                "failOnStderr": "false",
                                "showWarnings": "false",
                                "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
                                "pwsh": "false",
                                "workingDirectory": "",
                                "runScriptInSeparateScope": "false"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

To get the Deployment Group ID, you can navigate to **Pipelines -> Deployment Groups -> Target Deployment Group** and check the mgid in the url.

[image]

On the other hand, you can also use this Rest API: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the definition of an existing release pipeline and check the response to get the required request body content